# Remove port number from URL for my docker sites

Tags: docker, nginx, web

I have a VPS is running to web sites by docker.

`foo.com` works great, which is running by `docker run -p 80:80 fooV1`.

Then I want to host one my site by another docker container.

I want to use `anotherfoo.com` without port number. But as the VPS 80 port is using my `foo.com` container, I can only use `docker run -p 9000:80 anotherfooV1` then when access I have to use port number.
`anotherfoo.com:9000` to access.

I know Nginx has a reverse proxy for doing such so, but does it work for docker containers too?

How to remove the `9000` from my `anotheroo.com:9000`?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could install any front server (Apache/Nginx i.e) in your VPS and later configure a Reverse Proxy.

For example, this is a configuration for Apache (.conf) and 9000 port. Most of VPS came with Apache inside the control panel but I don't know if it is your case.

```
<VirtualHost yourhost.com:80>
   ProxyPreserveHost On

   ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
</VirtualHost>
```

[Docs from Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/reverse-proxy-configuration-apache/)
[Apache's official doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html)